# C# Getter/Setter problem

Tags: c#, field, getter-setter

Say i have a property in a class:

```
Vector3 position{get; set;}
```

So i create an instance of that class somewhere and now i want to change position.x, that would be impossible now because the getter and setter set and get the whole object. So i have to make a temporary Vector3 change its values and then assign it.

Normally i would make position a public field so that problem would be solved. But i cant do it in this case because position is an implementation of an interface and interfaces cant have fields.

So how can i solve this the best way.

Edit: Vector3 is a struct so its a value type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, the easiest answer here:

```
private Vector3 position;
public Vector3 Position {
    get {return position;}
    set {position = value;} // with @Mehrdad's optimisation
}
public float X {
    get {return position.X;}
    set {position.X = value;}
}
public float Y {
    get {return position.Y;}
    set {position.Y = value;}
}
public float Z {
    get {return position.Z;}
    set {position.Z = value;}
}
```

Now you can change `obj.X`, `obj.Y` and `obj.Z` if you only need to change one dimension, or change `obj.Position` to change everything.

If you need the name `position` to implement an interface, then do it explicitly:

```
Vector3 IWhateverInterface.position {
    get {return position;}
    set {position = value;}
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what i thought about but like i explained in the comments above position will be modified allot so is this the most efficient way? Reading the answers i assume this is the only way am i right ?

Comment: This is essentially identical to providing methods. A possible micro-optimization is to avoid using automatic properties for `Position` and directly modify `position.X` in the `X` property.

Comment: @slayerIQ you have to pick your battle. If that is the problem you *could* just expose `position` as the field, and do the explicit interface implementation as per the bit I added at the end?

Comment: Thanks i'll go with the explicit interface implementation of position :)

Comment: @Mehrdad you are correct. It is late... modified (with credit)

Answer (score 9):

Is the straightforward solution somehow not acceptable?

```
foo.position = new Vector(newX, foo.position.Y, foo.position.Z);
```

What's wrong with that? It seems perfectly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the issues with mutable value types. You can create a new instance of the value type with the new `X` value and reassign in to the property. You can make the instance creation easier by providing useful constructors or adding methods that return a modified object (instead of modifying the value).

Comment: The problem is that position will be changed allot. So creating a new instance or calling a method every time i want to modify the property would be overkill.

Comment: @slayerIQ: You can't modify this in the interface. Either you'll have to make `Vector3` a class (which is probably less than ideal) or provide methods that modify position in the interface (with things like `MoveHorizontally(float distance)`) or just have the clients assign the property like `obj.Position = new Vector3(obj.Position.X + 10, obj.Position.Y, obj.Position.Z);`. This problem doesn't really have a better solution (the canonical example is Windows Forms with the `Location` and `Size` properties of the `Control` class).

Comment: slayerIQ never said that Vector3 is a value type. In fact, the post says it is a class. Whether that's a typo or not isn't clear.

Comment: @Eilon: If `Vector3` was a reference type, you could easily do `obj.Position.X += 10;` without any issues and you wouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Right, but it isn't clear to me that slayerIQ actually tried that (or knew it was possible). I don't see any mention of compilation errors or runtime errors.

Comment: Vector3 is a struct, Sorry for not specifying that in the question.

Comment: I assume it is indeed a struct - this struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx; sorry @Mehrdad, I would upvote but I'm all out for today.

Comment: @Marc: Don't worry. I'm above the cap ;)

Comment: Eilon, you didn't read carefully.  He said this is a property in a class.  He didn't say `Vector3` is itself a class.

Comment: @Kyralessa, good point. I misinterpreted the "that" to mean `Vector3` and not the containing class.